# Simplest way to create an exact copy of a vector in R?

Tags: arrays, r, list, vector, copy

I am trying to create a copy of a vector in R... let's call it `list_foo`.

I want to create another list called `list_bar`, an exact copy of `list_foo` with all of the same elements and length. What is the simplest way to go about doing this in R?

Solutions without importing libraries are preferred.

Comment: `list_bar <- list_foo`?

Comment: @DamianoFantini that doesn't copy anything, they both refer to the same object in memory `x = c(1, 2, 3); y = x; pryr::address(x) == pryr::address(y)`

Comment: @ScottWarchal Correct, unless you modify one of the objects... I addressed this point in my answer. Still, I don't think you have reasons to worry about this, since R handles the problem of updating objects in memory very well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in Ken's answer and in my comment, I think that 99% of the R community will suggest you to use the `<-` operator. However, the comment about the location of the 2 objects in memory is correct.

```
library(pryr)
x <- c(1, 2, 3) 
y <- x
pryr::address(x) == pryr::address(y) #true
pryr::address(x)
# [1] "0x5832a668"
```

Now, what happens if you modify one of them?

```
x <- "hello world"
x
# [1] "hello world" # updated x, new location in the memory
pryr::address(x)
# [1] "0xa72aab88"
y
# [1] 1 2 3 #still the same
pryr::address(y)
# [1] "0x5832a668"
```

R takes care of handling where the object is stored and creates automatically a new location for the object that is updated. So you don't have to worry. Do you really want a copy, even if R can take care of this on its own? If so (and if your object is a vector), you can use `sapply` for example (or `lapply` for a list, or more complex approaches for other types of structures).

```
# the 'y' object
y
# [1] 1 2 3
pryr::address(y)
# [1] "0x7d10bf68"

# let's create a copy of 'y' using sapply()
x <- sapply(y, function(i) i)  

# same vector, different location in the memory
pryr::address(x)
# [1] "0x5a8755b0"

# are they really identical? Yes
identical(x, y)  
# [1] TRUE
```

However, I don't see a reason you really don't want to take advantage of `x <- y`. It's so easy!

Comment: A possible advantage is when you're using GraalVM with FastR. When you call an RScript using java the `x <- y` becomes a reference copying instead of what R normally does. So one needs to enforce copying in order for the code to work in GraalVM

Answer (score 0):

R is not like Python, where variable names are actually pointer to objects.

In Python you'd need the additional libraries (like `copy`) you were not preferring. In `R` you can just do this and a new object called `list_bar` is created:

```
list_bar <- list_foo
```

Comment: Unless you modify one of them they are same object.

Answer (score 0):

The {collapse} package allows to deliberately modify data by reference:

```r
v <- 1:10
p <- v
collapse::setop(p, "-", 1L)
v
# [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Here creating a copy of the vector using `[]` (or `collapse::ss()`, which is faster) might be safer:

```
v <- 1:10
p <- v[]
collapse::setop(p, "-", 1L)
v
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

(Note that the {data.table} package which allows to work on rectangular data by reference uses `[]` as a mere shortcut for `print()`. Here, `data.table::copy()` is the way to go.)